# Why BaseAdapter does not need parenthesis?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am asking why I cannot write this:

```
class myClass : BaseAdapter() {
        }
```

Instead of this:

```
class myClass : BaseAdapter {
        }
```

BaseAdapter is an interface.

Answer (score 2):

`BaseAdapter` is an `abstract` class, not an `interface`. In Kotlin, if you extend from a class (`abstract` or otherwise), you need to use the constructor invocation.

If you start with this:

```
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class myClass : BaseAdapter() {

}
```

...you will get an error:

[image: Android Studio, Showing Error]

That is because you are missing the functions required by the `abstract` class. If you put your text cursor in the `class myClass` error area and press <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd>, you can choose "Implement methods", select all four methods, and Android Studio will code-generate `TODO()` implementations of those methods for you:

```
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class myClass : BaseAdapter() {
  override fun getView(
    position: Int,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
  ): View {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  override fun getCount(): Int {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

}
```

At this point, you should have no further errors.

Comment: Ok but why I can't write `class myClass : BaseAdapter() {
        }`

Comment: @John: Well, you can, but you will need to add some functions or mark `myClass` as `abstract`. If you are using Android Studio, and you hover your mouse over the `class myClass` with the red undersquiggle, you will get a tooltip explaining the problem.

Comment: I tried but I got this message : "supertype initialization is impossible without primary constructor"

Comment: @John: Are you using `android.widget.BaseAdapter`?

Comment: I use this import android.widget.BaseAdapter

Comment: @John: I do not know how you are getting that. I updated my answer to show more information about building a stub implementation of `myClass`.

Comment: @CommonsWare,simple and perfect answer.